# Help finishing a logic proof?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have been working on the following proof:

Every fetus has an immortal soul.
A thing has an immortal soul only if it has a right to life. Hence, every fetus has a right to life. (Fx = x is a fetus, Sx = x has an immortal soul, Rx = x has a right to life).

(x)(Fx → Sx)
(x)(Rx → Sx)            ∴ (x)(Fx → Rx)

I believe I got the symbolization correct, but if I did not please someone let me know. The proof I have up to this point is as follows:

(x)(Fx → Sx)
(x)(Rx → Sx)            ∴ (x)(Fx → Rx)
Fa                      Assume (for CP)
Fa → Sa                 1, UI
Sa                      4, 3, MP
Ra → Sa                 2, UI

At this point I was working on a conditional proof but I need to get "Ra" out of this one and I can't figure out the next step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Perhaps a more realistic example would help. Suppose that every unicorn has silver hooves, and that a thing has silver hooves only if it has eight legs. Show that every unicorn would then have eight legs.

Comment: To be honest, the example I am giving is the same one that my professor provided for my class. I had no part in constructing the example or the topic.

Comment: That's just creepy. He/she shouldn't use a class in logic to promote his extreme religious views.

Answer (score 2):

Politics/religion/morality aside...$P$ only if $Q$ translates to $P\rightarrow Q$

Comment: The "only if" thing seems to be a point of debate among people. I guess I will try it both ways because I've seen people say it means that since P can only exist if Q is there, then Q > P is the right configuration. But that's one thing down.... thank you.

Comment: Hmm...$P$ if and only if $Q$ means implication in both directions.  But $P$ if $Q$ certainly means $Q\rightarrow P$.  So the 'only if' must give the other implication, $P\rightarrow Q$.

Comment: Interesting interpretation....I think that makes sense now. Believe it or not my textbook was not a useful source for this information.

Comment: See also: "It will rain *only if* there are clouds" and "There will be clouds *if* it is raining." $$\text{Rain}\to\text{Clouds}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I often use:

'You can be a bachelor only if you are male'

Using $B$ for 'you are a bachelor', and $M$ for 'you are male', should we translate this as:

$$M \rightarrow B$$

or

$$B \rightarrow M$$

I hope it is clear that the second translation is what we want: the first one ends up saying that you are a bachelor as soon as we know you are male, but of course that is not the case: you also have to be unmarried.  But what is the case is that when you tell me that you are a bachelor, I then also know you are a male, since only males can be bachelors.

And so yes, in general, '$P$ only if $Q$' translates as:

$$P \rightarrow Q$$